# Remove leading 0s (in single-digit month and day) from datestr(, 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I wish to remove the leading zeros in `mm` and `dd` from the following date format `yyyy-mm-dd`, and hope to get relevant feedback on my attempt.

To illustrate my point, `dat=datestr(now-1,'yyyy-mm-dd')` ends up with `2016-03-07`, However my wish is to retrieve `2016-3-7`.

So far I've attempted to work out on a sub-optimal code, leading to `216-3-7`.

```
dat=datestr(now-1,'yyyy-mm-dd');
o=ones(size(result));
z=strfind(dat,'0');
o(zero)=0;
msb=find(mask~=0);
res=dat(msb)
```

I concede the task is quite tricky, because not all `0s` from `mm` and `dd` should be removed by default, but only the single-digit `mm` and `dd` (let's say from 1-9) which come out with a leading zero when using the `datestr()` function.

Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such forma supported by datestr, you have to use generic functions like `sprintf` to format it

```
x=datevec(now-1);
res=sprintf('%d-%d-%d',x(1),x(2),x(3));
```